# com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ',3'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, truncation

I'm trying to write a shop plugin for my Minecraft server, but I keep getting an error whenever anyone does the /purchase command.

Here's the error:

```
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ',3'
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3591)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1662)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1581)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at com.Chipmunk9998.Cod.CodCommandExecutor.onCommand(CodCommandExecutor.java:1421)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:40)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:166)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:479)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at com.Chipmunk9998.Cod.CodCommandExecutor.onCommand(CodCommandExecutor.java:1443)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:40)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:166)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:479)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.handleCommand(NetServerHandler.java:821)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.chat(NetServerHandler.java:781)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:764)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.Packet3Chat.handle(Packet3Chat.java:34)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkManager.b(NetworkManager.java:229)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:113)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkListenThread.a(NetworkListenThread.java:78)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:567)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:459)
2012-07-03 04:27:28 [SEVERE]    at net.minecraft.server.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:492)
```

And here's my code:

```
if (cmdsender == null) {
  File weaponFile = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "weapons.yml");
  FileConfiguration weaponData = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(weaponFile);

  String sql = "UPDATE account_info SET Money = Money - "
    + weaponData.getString(args[0] + "." + args[1] + ".Price")
    + " WHERE Username = '" + args[2] + "'";

  try {
    plugin.st.executeUpdate(sql);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  sql = "UPDATE account_info SET Bought_" + args[0] + " = Bought_" + args[0]
    + " + ," + args[1] + " WHERE Username = '" + args[2] + "'";

  try {
    plugin.st.executeUpdate(sql);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  plugin.getServer().getPlayer(args[2]).sendMessage(
    "You have successfully bought the "
    + weaponData.getString(args[0] + "." + args[1] + ".Name") + "."
  );

  return true;
}
```

I tried googling it, but couldn't find anything that helped.

Comment: I'm guessing this has to do with your args[]. Can you do a simple System.out.println() of your args[] to check their values?

Comment: just write and check sql like System.out.println(sql); I think value which is expected as double is passed as string which has , comma. So which causes the query to fail.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have an error in this line:

```
  sql = "UPDATE account_info SET Bought_" + args[0] + " = Bought_" + args[0]
    + " + ," + args[1] + " WHERE Username = '" + args[2] + "'";
```

There is an erroneous comma in this string before `args[1]`.  If `args[0]`, `args[1]` and `args[2]` contain `1`, `3` and `foo` respectively, then `sql` will evaluate to:

```sql
UPDATE account_info SET Bought_1 = Bought_1 + ,3 WHERE Username = 'foo'
```

Which is clearly a syntax error and explains your error message `Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ',3'`.

Comment: I was trying to add the comma as a way to split the string up so I could list all the items they have and let them select which one they wanted to use. Is there any way around that, or a different character I can put there?

Comment: @DavidCarpenter:  To do that, you would need to use MySQL's [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function and quote your string literals e.g. `... = CONCAT(Bought_" + args[0] + ", '," + args[1] + "') WHERE ...`. However, you should probably [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data structure by storing e.g. `(Username, Bought)` pairs in a separate table, with which you could then [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) your queries as appropriate.

Answer (score -2):

I was coding in JSP for updating database records using UPDATE query.
"UPDATE customer_details set Customer_fname=?,Customer_lname=?,Customer_home_address=?,Customer_office_address=?,Customer_mobile_no=?,Customer_city=?,Customer_state=?,Customer_dob=? where **User_id=?**

in last User_id's parameter...., I accidentally write **ps.setString(9,uname)** which was different variable with different datatype....which give me an error of **data truncation:incorrect doublevalue**.

i corrected it with **ps.setInt(9,uid)** which was correct variable and  datatype then error was gone....!!